# Polymer and GWT, not working with Firefox

Tags: firefox, gwt, polymer-2.x

In short, from within Java, after onModuleLoad(), we do the following:

```
String resource = "bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js";
ScriptInjector.fromUrl(resource).setCallback(successCallback).inject();
```

Once the injection is successful, we inject html import links into the page:

```
private void injectImport(String href)
{
    HeadElement docHead = getHead();
    LinkElement link = Document.get().createLinkElement();
    link.setHref(href);
    link.setRel("import");
    docHead.appendChild(link);
}
```

On chrome, we can see from the network tab that the the import html files are indeed being GETed, and everything works as expected.

However, on Firefox, the injects are successful into the DOM, but the network tab reports that no resources we're GETed.

I know that HTML imports are not natively supported by Firefox, but I assumed once we had injected the polyfill from webcomponents-lite.js, it should just "work". Is this not the case?

Comment: Fascinating, do you have any examples of that in github or somewhere I can take a look?

Comment: No, it's all code I can't make public.